# How to build object hierarchy such that all nouns are words but not all words are nouns

Tags: arrays, class, swift, tableview, superclass

I have a couple of classes that represent parts of speech (nouns, verbs, adjectives, pronouns...) written in swift. I want to display instances of these classes in the same table view. All of these classes are types of words so technically there should be a class called word that is the superclass of noun.swift, verb.swift, adjective.swift and the others. Not all of those word types have the same member variables. How should I go about reconciling these objects as different types of words.

Alternatively I have been considering making the array of the type Any and adding objects of different types to it. That array will hold all of the values in the table view. The issue there is passing the object of undeclared type to the detailViewController.

If anyone has any advice on how to proceed it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why you pass undeclared variable. Use type `Word` which is a super class in your case for all other class. So unwrapping array objects to `Word` class will solve your issue.

Comment: Because I don't actually have a class called word and it was only an idea. I created the part of speech classes first without thinking about them being subclasses. Also I don't completely understand class inheritance when the two objects share no member variables.

Comment: @Jkallus You don't need to share any member variables for one class to be derived from another. You could have no variables in your base class at all, and still derive all the other classes from it, and use collections of Word type that hold all the subtypes. It's just that when there's an "is-a" relationship—i.e. "a verb is a word", "a noun is a word", then typically there will also often be shared attributes. But there don't *have* to be. We'd need to know a bit more about the shared behaviour of your different types to recommend a solution. What does detailViewController *do* with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** nouns, verbs, etc are in fact types of words then that **must** be captured in the type hierarchy.  As soon as you wrote `class Noun` and then `class Verb` you needed to stop and define the superclass.

```
class Word {}
class Noun : Word { /* ... */ }
class Verb : Word { /* ... */ }
```

The above is the minimum; the starting point.  From here, you add state or behavior to `Word` as you recognize that `Noun` and `Verb` share something.

Now you can have arrays of words.  Of course, if there is no state nor behavior associated with a `Word` then all users of that array will forever be down casting to one of the subtypes:

```
override func tableView (tableView: UITableView, 
 cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = ...
  let word = words[indexPath.row]

  if let noun = word as? Noun { cell.text = /* noun stuff */ }
  else if let verb = word as? Verb { cell.text = /* verb stuff */ }

  return cell
}
```

But I suspect, once you've defined `Word`, you'll find stuff to put in it which will make the above `word as? Noun` code less onerous.

Note regarding the type hierarchy: I'd say, strictly, nouns and verbs are actually [parts of speech](http://arts.uottawa.ca/writingcentre/en/hypergrammar/the-parts-of-speech) and that a word can be associated with multiple parts of speech.  Modeled as such:

```
class PartOfSpeech {}
class Noun : PartOfSpeech {}
class Verb : PartOfSpeech {}

class Word { var partsOfSpeech : Set<PartOfSpeech> }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm about to go implement this